# stacking images side by side

Tags: graphics

Image1 [image]

Image2 [image]

I am using a template version from the internet for Latex. It has a class file where the position and the attribute of the title page are defined.

```
\UNIVERSITY  {}{\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{image1.jpg}}
    \hfill
    \href{}{\includegraphics[width=5.7cm]{image2.jpg}}}
```

In my main `.tex` file

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

% Set up the Title Page
\title  {}
\authors  {\texorpdfstring
            {\textbf{}}
            {}
            }
\addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname}  % Do not change this here, instead these must be set in the "Thesis.cls" file, please look through it instead
\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}

\maketitle
\end{document}
\setstretch{1.3}  % It is better to have smaller font and larger line spacing than the other way round

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{70mm}
```

The above code creates two images side by side. Image 1 is vertical and image 2 is horizontal. The vertical image is totally big and thus occupying too much space. Is there a way to make two images aesthetically look better by placing it side by side in the title page.

I need something like this

[image]

Comment: Can you give a MWE (Minimal Working Example) ?

Comment: You could change the `width=` to `height=` in the `\includegraphics`, perhaps.  Without seeing the images, or the class file, it is difficult to resolve in the blind.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the first few lines are the code which represents the images. I will add the figures now.

Comment: Since the image 1 is big I am very much perplexed n how to fix the size of image. when I reduce the size of image 1, it gets pixelated.

Comment: I think you are still going to have to provide us an idea of what you want the result to look like.  Maybe cut and paste a graphic, scan it and post it.

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: When I use jpegs with pdflatex, I can zoom in to the original image resolution.